# Backbone.js adding model retrieved from server to a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to know if it possible to add a model to a collection in the following manner.
I tried it and it doesn't work.  If I add the JSON [] directly it does. I know this is a little strange but I am trying to get a better understanding of how BB works. Thanks.

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/users',
});

var UserModels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/users',
    model: UserModel
});

var user = new UserModel({id:1});
user.fetch({  // get the model
    success: function (user) {
        var users = new UserModels();
        users.add(user); // add the model to a collection
    }
});
```

The following model is being echoed from the server:

```
[{"name":"john","email":"john@bb.com"}]
```

Comment: That should work fine. The only issue I see is that you are returning a list of models rather than a single model. This seems wrong since you are fetching a single model.

Comment: What are you seeing in the response for the ajax call (in dev tools)?

Comment: The answer below works.  I think that adding an array with one element to a collection is problematic. The [] need to be stripped off for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the response from the server is an array with a single element, you will need to add a [parse function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) that returns the first element of the array:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/users',
    parse: function(response){
        if(response && response.length) return response[0];
    }
});
```

That should allow the model to correctly parse the attributes in this response from the server: `[{"name":"john","email":"john@bb.com"}]`.

By the way, you are creating the users collection in the success function, so it won´t be available outside that function. It might just be the sample code you posted, but you could create the users collection outside and just add the model in the success function:

```
var users = new UserModels();
var user = new UserModel({id:1});
user.fetch({  // get the model
    success: function (user) {
        users.add(user); // add the model to a collection
    }
});
```

I have [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftvu7wn4/) so you can give it a try. (I have used fiddle echo service, so thats why I have changed the url and it is using a POST). If you run it and check the console, you will see the users collection being logged and you can check its `models` property.

Comment: Excellent.  Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work fine without the parse function for PUT and POST requests. Only GET users/id seems to need it. Is there an explanation for that?

Comment: The fiddle is using a POST. If I remove the parse function, the collection gets one model but the model has incorrect attributes (It ends with original attribute id and another attribute named "0" with the name and email)